# Does the Natural Armor a Synthesist Summoner Gains from a Fused Eidolon Stack with Base Race's Natural Armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am playing a race in my home game that has a base natural armor of 4, and I am also playing a synthesist summoner.  Does my eidolon's natural armor bonus stack with my characters base natural armor, or does it not stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### They don't, but they don't really need to.

> Generally speaking, most bonuses of the same type do not stack. Instead, only the highest bonus applies.

So your Natural Armor bonus will not stack with that of your Eidolon, since both bonuses are of the same type, and there is no exception to the general rule found for the Fused Eidolon ability.

However, look at the following parts

> **[Fused Eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist)**
>
> [...] The synthesist uses the eidolon’s base attack bonus, and **gains the eidolon’s armor and natural armor bonuses** and modifiers to ability scores. [...]
>
> While fused, the synthesist loses the benefits of his armor.

(emphasis mine) Note that you do not lose your Natural Armor while fused (because the rules don't say so)

> **[Armor Bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Armor-Bonus)**
> The number noted here is the eidolon’s base total armor bonus. This bonus **may be split between an armor bonus and a natural armor bonus**, as decided by the summoner. [...]

So instead of taking your Eidolons Natural Armor Bonuses, set them to zero. Put all your Eidolons Armor Bonus to regular armor and keep your own Natural Armor.

Comment: If I am not mistaken there is an exception to natural armor for this rule. If I remember correctly magically gained natural armor stacks with racial natural armor. But I think you are right, they don't stack

Comment: @DanceSC I believe you are thinking of [this description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Natural-Armor-Bonus): "[...]Natural armor bonuses stack with all other bonuses to armor class (even with armor bonuses) except other natural armor bonuses. Some magical effects (such as the *barkskin* spell) grant an enhancement bonus to the creature's existing natural armor bonus, which has the effect of increasing the natural armor's overall bonus to armor class.[...]" But Fused Eidolon grants Natural Armor, not an Enhancement Bonus to Natural Armor, so it doesn't apply here.